# How to carete dynamic NavBar with only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, dom

I have this code right now, but its not working on the DOM, I am wondering what is the problem with my code. My current code:

"JavaScript"

```
const sectionElements = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const menuList = document.getElementById('navbar__list');

function NavBarCreate (){
    for (let i = 0; i < sectionElements.length; i++){
        const listStart = document.createElement('li');
        const attributeId = sectionElements[i].getAttribute('id');
        const attributeName = sectionElements[i].getAttribute('data-nav');
        listStart.innerHTML = 
        `<a href="${attributeId}" class="menu__link">${attributeName}</a>`;
        menuList.appendChild(listStart);   
    }
}
```

"HTML"

```
<nav class="navbar__menu">
   <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
</nav>
<main>
<section  id="section1" data-nav="Section 1">
</section>

<section  id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">
</section>
</main>
```

<

Comment: Your code is OK, you should invoke the function like this NavBarCreate();

Comment: was a problem with a script i wrote, i was calling the file from different folder like './js/app' but i should 'js/app.js' thanks man!

Comment: You are welcome man, and you can try this function. This is much cleaner

`function NavBarCreate() {
  for (let i = 0; i < sectionElements.length; i++) {
    const listStart = document.createElement('ul');
    const {
      id,
      dataset: { nav },
    } = sectionElements[i];

    listStart.innerHTML = `
      <li>
        <a href="${id}" class="menu__link">${nav}</a>
      </li>
    `;
    menuList.appendChild(listStart);
  }
}`

Comment: Thank you man, that indeed looks clean!! Do you know how to Scroll to anchor ID using scrollTO event```
const scrollDownsmooth = () => { 
    document.querySelectorAll(".menu__link").forEach(anchor => {
        anchor.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth'
            });
        });
    });
}; """""" what do you think about this code?

Comment: Just like this, e.target gets the target dom, `const scrollDownsmooth = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.menu__link').forEach((anchor) => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.target.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    });
  });
};
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call the function or avoid the function. try it